# Have onclick event not refresh with each page?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, buttonclick

I have a translation feature that switches paragraphs from english to french using javascript at the click of a button. Now I manually grabbed each paragraph using innerhtml and everything works fine. When I switch from one page to another if the user already translated that page to french it should carry over to every other page. Though right now when linking to another page it refreshes and reverts back to english forcing the user to keep translating the page every time it refreshed which I DONT want.

Based on how I set up these functions I don't know if its possible to do this now, I basically want one onlick event to translate all the pages, basically don't want this function to refresh when entering another page.

```js
function translate_fr(){
document.getElementById("servicesIntro").innerHTML = `Nous proposons de nombreux services supplémentaires pour votre chat. Lorsque vous réservez avec nous, vous pouvez choisir parmi l'une des options ci-dessous. Si nécessaire, tout ajustement apporté à nos prix sera discuté une fois le rendez-vous pris. Toute autre question ou préoccupation peut être discutée avec nous lorsque vous prenez rendez-vous. N'hésitez pas à nous appeler, nous envoyer un e-mail ou même nous contacter via nos réseaux sociaux pendant nos heures de travail de 9h à 18h du mardi au samedi.`
}
```

```html
<button class="translate" type="button" onclick="translate_fr()">FR</button>

<p id="servicesIntro"><span class="firstWord">We</span> offer many additional services for your cat, when you book with us you can choose from any of the options below. If needed any adjustments made to our prices will be discussed once an appointment is made. Any other questions or concerns can be discussed with us when you book an appointment. Feel free to call, e-mail us or even contact us through our social media during our work hours from 9 A.M to 6 P.M Tuesday to Saturday.
</p>
```

Comment: Every page is its own isolated world. What you ask is impossible. You need to get more creative, like caching results in local storage and reapplying them automatically.

Comment: You need to pass along a value to indicate that the new page should or shouldn't translate by default.  Then check the value on page load and run your translation logic if the value says it should be translated.  You can pass that value via GET or via POST.  If you don't currently POST before loading the new page, then it's likely easiest to use GET and pass an url parameter that indicates whether or not to automatically translate

Comment: Hmmm ok, so basically when the user clicks that button, every other page visited after that should check for that action, and either run my translation function or not. Not even sure where to begin as I am more a front end developer. I assume it can be done with conditional statements, can I achieve this using javascript? I am a little familiar with php syntax

Comment: I'd look into setting a cookie and reading that on subsequent pages.

Comment: I am not familiar with cookies, (just out of school) though just reading up on it they seem very easy to use. If I can carry over the functions action from one page to the next using this I will do so and post my result.